# Why is time multiplied by coupling constant in this graph?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I've encountered this plot

[image: Plot of time-dependent Z expectation values of a two-qubit system.]

within a paper which plots the dynamics of a two-qubit system in terms of expectation values. In this plot, the time axis is multiplied by $g$ which is a coupling term that comes from the system Hamiltonain

$H = \omega \sigma_z^{(a)} +  (\omega + \delta) \sigma_z^{(b)} + g(\sigma_x^{(a)} \sigma_x^{(b)} + \sigma_y^{(a)} \sigma_y^{(b)})$.

In this example $\omega$ is given in terms of the coupling constant $\omega = 1000g$. I'm wondering why does it help to multiply the time axis by the coupling constant in this instance? Is it just so that the scale of the dynamics is in multiples of $g$?

Answer (score 0):

To study the dynamics, you will have a time evolution operator that looks  something like $U=\exp(-i H t)$ (where the argument is just some operators times $g)$. To avoid worrying about units in your plots, you can plot the evolution of the system as a function of the only parameter in the argument of $U$, that is $gt=t/g^{-1}$. This is often done in theoretical papers.

Technicality: it should be $U=\exp(-i H t/\hbar)$, but I am assuming that they chose $\hbar=1$.